# How to store row for later use when generated element is clicked without updating page?

Tags: php, sql, database

How can I store the QuestionID of the specific clicked question generated by my query without adding it to the URL as I have done below?

I want to store the QuestionID value so that I can put it into my database with the IP address of my user (no login), without updating the page.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY QuestionVotes DESC LIMIT 4");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //$row["QuestionID"] to add id to url

    echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\"><h2>". $row["QuestionHeader"]. "</h2><p>". $row["QuestionText"]. "</p><p><a href=\"index.php?id=". $row["QuestionID"]. "\" class=\"btn btn-success\"> " . $row["QuestionVotes"] . "</a></p></div>";
    $id = $row["QuestionID"];
    }
}
else
{
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Table:

**Question:** QuestionID (PK), QuestionHeader, QuestionText, QuestionVotes

Comment: you could resort to cookies (readable from php) but why would you want to remove the url parameter in the first place ?

Comment: Using the url parameter updates the page everytime a button is clicked, this is both clunky, time-consuming and restarts site animations. I would very much like to avoid resorting to cookies tho, if at all possible.

Comment: then what you want is to fire an ajax query instead of the link, which would send the server the required data for storage and not refresh anything in the page if you're so inclined. The Id would still need to be passed as a parameter though.

Comment: The ID would still be passed in the url? Cause this seems to shut down my database for some reason. As soon as the url changes, everything generated by the database data disappears?

Comment: the point is to transmit the id to the server (thus the need for a query of some kind) without the behavior you don't want - the browser refreshing the whole page because the page url has changed. that won't happen with an ajax query.